# Package inputenc error unicode char

Tags: bibtex, unicode, cyrillic

Error with message `Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:<d0>. not set up for use with LaTeX` occurs, when I compile (*Ubuntu 14.04.1*, *texlive-full*) the document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{article:manoilov, 
  author      = {Новиков, Л.В. and Манойлов, В.В. and Сягаев, Н.А.},
  title       = {Метод разделения пиков в дуплете},
  journal     = {Известия Санкт-Перетрбургского государственного технлогического университета (технического университета)},
  year        = {2012}, 
  number      = {14}, 
  pages       = {107-108},
  language    = {russian},
  hyphenation = {russian}, 
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{gost2008s}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Appending `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D0}{\TH}` to peramble does nothing.

Changing `Новиков, Л.В. and Манойлов, В.В. and Сягаев, Н.А.` value to `Новиков and Манойлов and Сягаев` makes error to hide.

How to deal with such kind of errors?

Comment: Strange, the `bbl` file shows `\BibEmph{Новиков~�., Манойлов~�., Сягаев~�.}`

Comment: @Sigur There are only simple blanks.

Comment: It is dangerous to use bibtex with utf8 files. It can insert line breaks in the bytes of a char.  With biblatex the example works fine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just starting to use TeX, thank you for the hint.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How to change example to use biblatex?

Comment: Curious. The problem is not related with `Л` but somehow with punctuation or spacing?

Comment: I use *vim latex-suite* to typing the text. Maybe problem is here?

Comment: @Orient I don't think so. I don't use it and also have the problem.

Comment: @Sigur: The curious symbols � were created by bibtex when trying to get the initials. It destroyed the utf8 multibytes.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, OK. The strange is that initial causes no problem when used in the middle of some word.

Comment: @Sigur: Replace the `Л.В.` in the first name by `Sigur` and then look what bibtex does with it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I got `S.`

Comment: @Sigur Exactly. The first byte of Sigur with a dot. And now think what will happen if bibtex extracts the first byte of a multibyte utf8 char like `Л`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, ow. Let me think about. I need to read about multibyte char.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `biblatex` and `biber` (which understands `utf8`)  there is no problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{article:manoilov,
  author = {Новиков, Л.В. and Манойлов, В.В. and Сягаев, Н.А.},
  title = {Метод разделения пиков в дуплете},
  journal = {Известия Санкт-Перетрбургского государственного технлогического университета (технического университета)},
  year = {2012},
  number = {14},
  pages = {107-108},
  language = {russian},
  hyphenation = {russian},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber, babel=other, style=gost-authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, but "References" section name is in English. How to deal with it?

Comment: @Orient If the document is in Russian, you should have `\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}`  (and omit `english` if you don't use that language).

Comment: I hadn't paid attention to this point. It's corrected now.

Comment: @egreg How to choose language for section name? I know I can write `\printbibliography[title={Список литературы}]`, but it should be chosen automatically.

Comment: @Orient It *is* chosen automatically based on the current language. With your input the current language at the start of the document is English, not Russian and, if you don't change to Russian mid way, it will still be English when `\printbibliography` is processed.

Comment: @Orient: See my updated code.